# Will this print a file?

Tags: java, file

What would this code do?

```
FileStream object = new FileStream("c:\input_final.txt",true);
```

I thought it would not run because they are not two \ and therefore see it as a escape character. Am I wrong and would it print/show/open the file?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: Whether you tried this??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a matter that could easily be answered by a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

No. It will not, because it is not legal code.

Unless you have a custom class `FileStream` (which you have not posted) then I assume you meant one of -

`FileOutputStream` which will not work because `c:\input_final.txt` is not a valid String; `\i` is not a valid escape sequence.

and

`FileInputStream` does not have a constructor that takes a boolean as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this print a file?

No.

1. It is not valid code.  It won't *compile* ... let alone run!
2. It is most likely that you mean something like this:

   ```
      ... = new FileOutputStream("c:\\input_final.txt",true);
   ```

   which says "create an output stream for appending to file "c:\input_final.txt".  But even that **WILL NOT** "print" or "show" the file, or "open" it in an application / browser / editor or whatever.